# jquery: ignore some ULs and LIs

Tags: jquery

I am using this example **(1)** and it works perfectly:
http://jsfiddle.net/dNfsJ/

but I also need to put a responsive menu there so I did this **(2)**:
http://jsfiddle.net/k0za95nw/1/

which is based on this menu: http://tympanus.net/Development/ResponsiveMultiLevelMenu/

but because JQuery is looping though the UL and LI tags in example **1**, it completely screws up example **2**.

How can I tell JQuery to ignore the ULs and LIs in the div with the ID **id="dl-menu"** ?

The code if you don't want to visit JSFiddle:

```
<ul id="original_items">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>



<!-- start the menu code -->

        <div id="dl-menu" class="dl-menuwrapper">

     <a href="#" class="dl-trigger"><img src="siteImgs/edit_gear_icon.png"></a>
    <ul class="dl-menu">
         <li>
            <a href="#">Use as album cover</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Delete</a>
        </li>

         <li>
            <a href="#">Thumbnails</a>
            <ul class="dl-submenu">
                <li><a href="#">Manually create thumb</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Use placeholder thumb</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div><!-- /dl-menuwrapper -->




    </li>
</ul>

<ul id="cloned_items">
</ul>
```

Comment: Post the relevant JS as well.. altho the answer is probably to use `not` - `$(selector).not("#dl-menu")`

Comment: Both of your fiddle examples work in Chrome.  But if your problem persists, just add the not selector like tymeJV said.

Comment: Sorry if my request was vague but I am still very much in the learning stage of CSS3 and JQuery... where do I use the NOT part?

Comment: This is my actual full code: http://pastebin.com/jY19EBUw , not sure where to put the not part...

Comment: (Updated the 2nd link, please view it again if you have viewed it before I made the changes.)

Comment: Please don't use tables for your layouts :( Use div/span/other elements and use the CSS to position and set layout

Comment: I plan on converting from the table to DIVs once this is working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want `not()`: http://api.jquery.com/not/

This will give you `ul`s that don't have the id `dl-menu`

```
$('ul').not('#dl-menu')
```

Comment: Can you tell me where in my code to put that please? I am still learning CSS3 / JQuery

Comment: wherever you are selecting your items now, put in this `not` clause

Comment: Ok, will try, the JS etc is here: http://jsfiddle.net/k0za95nw/1/ if you want to have a quick look at it while I fiddle around...

Comment: Trying to work with the jsfiddle that I mentioned above: it does not work, I'm not sure if I am using it wrong or if not() is not meant for the kind of javascript that is in the example...